# Is there some tactic for proving this apparently easy goal?

Tags: coq

I have the following goal:

1 subgoal

______________________________________(1/1)

(if (a =? a)%string || false then # a :: nil else nil) = nil

Since obviously a = a, I wonder why the tactic "simpl" doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
Print "=?".

String.eqb = 
fix eqb (s1 s2 : string) {struct s1} : bool :=
  match s1 with
  | "" => match s2 with
          | "" => true
          | String _ _ => false
          end
  | String c1 s1' =>
      match s2 with
      | "" => false
      | String c2 s2' => if Ascii.eqb c1 c2 then eqb s1' s2' else false
      end
  end
     : string -> string -> bool
```

`String.eqb` is defined as `fix` which means Coq won't reduce an application of it to an argument if Coq can't see the head symbol (constructor) of that argument. In this case the `simpl` tactic cannot apply `String.eqb a a`, because `a` is a variable, we don't know anything about its "shape" -- hence you see nothing.

By the way, `||`, i.e. `orb` function is defined by pattern-matching on its first argument, thus `simpl` cannot reduce `(a =? a)%string || false` to `(a =? a)%string`.

A way out here is to rewrite with `String.eqb_refl` lemma, after using this lemma it will be quite obvious that the goal is not provable unless you have a contradiction in the context, in which case you don't really need `String.eqb_refl`.